# UserManager.Find всегда возвращает null в Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2, asp.net-identity-3

На моём Asp.net Core 2.1 сайте все функции типа

```
userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

Возвращают `null`. Я использую пользователей и роли с `Id` типа `int`

```
public class UserGroup : IdentityRole<int> ...

public class User : IdentityUser<int> ...
```

Хотя в базе есть пользователи с этими именами и email. И это проверено через `ApplicationDbContext`.

Как я понимаю в `sturtup.cs` неправильно сконфигурированы сервисы необходимые для `UserManager`

Вот мой код.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserGroup>(
            options =>
            {
                /* pasword validation options */
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, UserGroup, ApplicationDbContext, int>>() /* тут я не знаю нужно это или нет, но эта строчка не помогает */
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Что я думаю на эту тему.**

**Первое**

Читаю [эту](https://medium.com/@nativoplus/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4) статью, и в ней есть вот такая строчка

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
```

Возможно она бы мне помогла, но в чём проблема, у меня есть только версия без `int`.

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

Что надо подключить что бы был нужный дженерик я не знаю.

**Второе**

Я у себя в версии смотрел что ASP.NET Core Identity версия 2.2.0
А в статье говорится про третью версию. Но третей нет на Nuget. Либо 2.2.0 это и есть третяя...

Answer (score 0):

Я заполнял базу через функцию `HasData` в `ModelBuilder`.

И я не заполнял вручную поля `NormalizedUserName` и `NormalizedEmail`.

Оказалось, что `UserManager` ищёт по ним.

Решилось заполнением их в функции `seed` вручную через `user.NormalizedUserName = user.Name.ToUpper()` и аналогично для email.